# How to make the visited link font normal even after the application is running again?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I am making the phonegap android application in html,javascript and jquery.I have made the link bold and visited link normal font.But when the run the application again or when the page is refreshed, i need to get the visited link in the same normal font.Please guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the :visited selector in CSS to style visited links:

a:visited{
    font-weight:normal !important;
}

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp

edit: I added `!important`. It overrides the default user style sheet in case that's the problem.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I have tried this example.Its working fine in browser,but its not working properly in my android emulator when i running the application again.Please guide me.

Comment: @user1126160, I'm not quite sure what's wrong, but you could try adding `!important`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I have tried using !important in the style.but the same problem occurs for me.Please guide me

Comment: @user1126160, I really don't know then, sorry.

Comment: @user1126160, Can you post ALL the css you are using. Also, what emulator?

Comment: Motrolladroid Emulator,same css which you have already mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something wouldn't setting visited link style the same as normal style solve your issue? In your CSS something like:

```
a:link, a:visited {... normal style declaration for links ...}
```